# PHP - Stop displaying full path in errors

Tags: php, security, error-handling

Is there any way I can tell PHP to NOT display full path of file having any error in Error, warning or notice messages. I know I can disable errors; But, just to avoid any risk.

For example: My script returns an error which is displayed like:

`Fatal error: Call to undefined function shell_exec1() in /home/[user]/public_html/index.php on line 1`

I want to display it like

`Fatal error: Call to undefined function shell_exec1() in ~/index.php on line 1`

This way, It'll be safer way to display error messages while not exposing full path of file to bad guys.

Is this possible? How?

Comment: In production, it is good practice to disable error reporting. What you need to do is introduce exception handling to your code..

Comment: Displaying the path if the least of your problems, displaying an error already gives a malicious user enough information to possibly exploiting your code.
I would recommend that you suppress the errors in your production server and just log them into a file and check it regularly.

Comment: @LifeQuery No, you should only disable technical error display and still log the errors for review.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just write your own error handler. see: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

```
function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    if (!(error_reporting() & $errno)) {
        // This error code is not included in error_reporting
        return;
    }

    switch ($errno) {
        case E_USER_ERROR:
        echo "<b>My ERROR</b> [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
        echo "  Fatal error on line $errline in file $errfile";
        echo ", PHP " . PHP_VERSION . " (" . PHP_OS . ")<br />\n";
        echo "Aborting...<br />\n";
        exit(1);
        break;

    case E_USER_WARNING:
        echo "<b>My WARNING</b> [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
        break;

    case E_USER_NOTICE:
        echo "<b>My NOTICE</b> [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
        break;

    default:
        echo "Unknown error type: [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
        break;
    }

    /* Don't execute PHP internal error handler */
    return true;
}

set_error_handler("myErrorHandler");
```

Comment: Amazing solution. Best answer.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested above use custom error handler. BUT cut the path with the basename() to achieve what you want.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php