# How to change an error displayed in php?

Tags: php, apache, runtime-error

I am working on an online editor project written in php.

I have an error message with the following format:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$type' (T_VARIABLE) in 
/home/server/public_html/code/index.php on line 4
```

But I want to display the error like this:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$type' (T_VARIABLE) in 
code/index.php on line 4
```

Is there any way I can hide server path from the error message?

Comment: you shouldn't be displaying error messages on production sites in the first place. log them, by all means, just don't let the user see them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - Stop displaying full path in errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21636337/php-stop-displaying-full-path-in-errors)

Comment: Its bad style to hide or change error messages. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern

Comment: @MarcB But it's a php online editor project, what if that's intended functionality?

Comment: then intercept the errors and re-write them. if it's an online editor that allows people to run their code, what's to stop someone from "testing" `<?php exec('rm -rf /'); ?>`?

Comment: Isn't he asking how he can intercept and re-write them? And I can't really answer that question as I don't know the scope/audience/assumptions of his project, just trying to defend a new user who is looking for help. In general though, I completely agree with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible.
You can use `set_error_handler()` to catch some kind of errors, but not this one.

`The following error types cannot be handled with a user defined function: E_ERROR, *E_PARSE*, E_CORE_ERROR, E_CORE_WARNING, E_COMPILE_ERROR, E_COMPILE_WARNING, and most of E_STRICT raised in the file where set_error_handler() is called.`

I suggest you to hide errors and redirect them to logfile, which is hidden from public.